# Sax Parsing strange element with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, sax

I want to sax-parse in nokogiri, but when it comes to parse xml element that have a long and crazy xml element name or a attribute on it.. then everthing goes crazy.

Fore instans if I like to parse this xml file and grab all the title element, how do I do that with nokogiri-sax.

```xml
<titles>
    <title xml:lang="sv">Arkivvetenskap</title>
    <title xml:lang="en">Archival science</title>
</titles>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, `title` is the name of the element. `xml:lang="sv"` is an attribute.
This parser assumes there are no elements nested inside of title elements

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

class MyDocument < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  def start_element(name, attrs)
    @attrs = attrs
    @content = ''
  end
  def end_element(name)
    if name == 'title'
      puts Hash[@attrs]['xml:lang']
      puts @content.inspect
      @content = nil
    end
  end
  def characters(string)
    @content << string if @content
  end
  def cdata_block(string)
    characters(string)
  end
end

parser = Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(MyDocument.new)
parser.parse(DATA)

__END__
<titles>
    <title xml:lang="sv">Arkivvetenskap</title>
    <title xml:lang="en">Archival science</title>
</titles>
```

This prints

```
sv
"Arkivvetenskap"
en
"Archival science"
```

SAX parsing is usually way too complex. Because of that, I recommend Nokogiri's standard in-memory parser, or if you **really** need speed and memory efficiency, [Nokogiri's Reader parser](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Reader.html).

For comparison, here is a standard Nokogiri parser for the same document

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(DATA)
doc.css('title').each do |title|
  puts title['lang']
  puts title.text.to_s.inspect
end

__END__
<titles>
    <title xml:lang="sv">Arkivvetenskap</title>
    <title xml:lang="en">Archival science</title>
</titles>
```

And here is a reader parser for the same document

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(DATA)
while reader.read
  if reader.name == 'title' && reader.node_type == Nokogiri::XML::Reader::TYPE_ELEMENT
    puts reader.attribute('xml:lang')
    puts reader.inner_xml.inspect # TODO xml decode this, if necessary.
  end
end

__END__
<titles>
    <title xml:lang="sv">Arkivvetenskap</title>
    <title xml:lang="en">Archival science</title>
</titles>
```

Comment: +1 for Reader suggestion. All the performance without all the SAX pain.

Comment: awesome @John Douthat, which type of parse do you recommend to use if you going to parse 10.000 xml that looks like this: https://gist.github.com/2282103?

Comment: I would use the standard Nokogiri in-memory parser. It's the easiest to code, and plenty fast as long as the document can fit in memory. Switch to the Reader parser if you're dealing with documents that are too large to fit in memory.